# Critical section negative lock count

Tags: deadlock

I am debugging a deadlock issue  and call stack shows that threads are waiting on some events.

Code is using critical section as synchronization primitive I think there is some issue here.
Also the debugger is pointing to a critical section that is owned by some other thread,but lock count is -2.
As per my understanding lock count>0 means that critical section is locked by one or more threads.

So is there any possibility that I am looking at right critical section which could be the culprit in deadlock.

In what scenarios can a critical section have negative lock count?

Comment: Raymond Chen has just written a post about the consequences of leaving a CS more times than entering it. And the first three comments are worth reading as well...  http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2009/06/19/9777996.aspx

Comment: @eran 's link is dead. Found it here though: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090619-00/?p=17823

Comment: Thanks @SamWhan. Too bad they dropped the comments when they moved to the new site, now I wonder what did the first three comments I referred to say :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming that you are talking about CCriticalSection class in MFC. I think you are looking at the right critical section. I have found that the critical section's lock count can go negative if the number of calls to Lock() function is less than the number of Unlock() calls. I found that this generally happens in the following type of code:

```
void f()
{
   CSingleLock lock(&m_synchronizer, TRUE);
   //Some logic here
   m_synchronizer.Unlock();
}
```

At the first glance this code looks perfectly safe. However, note that I am using CCriticalSection's Unlock() method directly instead of CSingleLock's Unlock() method. Now what happens is that when the function exits, CSingleLock in its destructor calls Unlock() of the critical section again and its lock count becomes negative. After this the application will be in a bad shape and strange things start to happen. If you are using MFC critical sections then do check for this type of problems.

Comment: LockCount depends on the version of Windows you're using: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff541979.aspx

Answer (score 31):

Beware: since Windows Server 2003 (for client OS [this is Vista and newer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/09/11/10557052.aspx)) the meaning of LockCount has changed and -2 is a completely normal value, commonly seen when a thread has entered a critical section without waiting and no other thread is waiting for the CS. See [Displaying a Critical Section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff541979(v=vs.85).aspx):

> In Microsoft Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1 and later versions of Windows, the LockCount field is parsed as follows:
>
> - The lowest bit shows the lock status. If this bit is 0, the critical section is locked; if it is 1, the critical section is not locked.
> - The next bit shows whether a thread has been woken for this lock. If this bit is 0, then a thread has been woken for this lock; if it is 1, no thread has been woken.
> - The remaining bits are the ones-complement of the number of threads waiting for the lock.

Comment: Wonderful information I haven't seen elsewhere. Helped me to resolve some wierd behavior on the part of critical sections.

Comment: Ditto to @mistiano's comment. I didn't know Microsoft had changed the way LockCount works in Server 2003 & above. The link was VERY useful!